# VSTO Word multiple lines in content control

Tags: c#, ms-word, office365, vsto

Is it somehow possible to add content control over multiple lines?

Currently I am adding content control like that:

```
bm = doc.Bookmarks.Add("bookmark", app.Selection.Range);
ContentControl cc = doc.ContentControls.Add(WdContentControlType.wdContentControlRichText, bm.Range);
cc.MultiLine = true;
cc.Tag = _BOOKMARK;
```

But I always get a ComException when I select/mark multiple lines in word and try to add a content control for them. Is it allowed or possible to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Inserting a content control "around" lines of text already in the document doesn't work, as far as I know.

Instead, assign the multiple lines to a `Range` object. Insert the content control, then use the `Range.FormattedText` property to "copy" these lines into it. Aftwards, delete the `Range`. Something like this (typed off the top of my head as I'm at a mobile device)

```
Word.Range rngSel = app.Selection.Range;
bm = doc.Bookmarks.Add("bookmark", rngSel);
Word.Range rngCC = rngSel.Duplicate;
//Insert the content control immediately after the selection, for example
rngCC.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
ContentControl cc = doc.ContentControls.Add(WdContentControlType.wdContentControlRichText, rngCC);
cc.MultiLine = true;
cc.Tag = _BOOKMARK;
cc.Range.FormattedText = rngSel.FormattedText;
RngSel.Delete();
```